# Bash pattern for dot-started directories excluding . and

Tags: bash

Quick example - I would like to list content of all `~/.*` directories, so:

```
ls -la ~/.*
```

However it lists also all current dir `.` and upper dir `..`

How can I exclude `.` and `..` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer to do it with regexp:

```
ls -la ~/.[^.]*
```

Answer (score 5):

From ls man-page:

```
-A, --almost-all
              do not list implied . and ..
```

so it will be:

```
ls -lA ~/.*
```

Comment: Ok, what about then other commands, for example `du -sh ~/.*` ?

Comment: @perreal that command does not exclude . and .. on fedora 17 at least

Comment: my bad, you need to remove the `a` flag